# Alter filename of image, based on select box

Tags: jquery, regex

**HTML:**

```
<div id="product-main-image">
     <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
<select id="selection" name="selection">
    <option value="someval1"> Red </option>
    <option value="someval2"> Blue </option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery("#selection").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        jQuery("#selection option:selected").each(function() {
            str += jQuery( this ).text() + " ";
        });
        str = str.toLowerCase().trim(); //red or blue

        var new_img = jQuery("#product-main-image img").attr('data-zoom-image'); //here i get path/to/image.jpg
        //what now??
});
```

**RESULT:**
I should get path/to/image-red.jpg or path/to/image-red.jpg

**NOTE:** Extension can be jpg, jpeg, png, gif etc.

Comment: Try `new_img = new_img.replace(/(\.[a-z]{3,4})$/,'-'+str+'$1')` which replaces `.ext` with `-str.ext` (any 3 or 4 char extension)

Comment: Great, It work. Will soon accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a fairly simple regex based replace like so:

```
var str = 'red';
var new_img = 'path/to/image.jpg';
new_img = new_img.replace(/(\.[a-z]{3,4})$/,'-'+str+'$1');
console.log(new_img); //"path/to/image-red.jpg"
```

(you should be able to copy and paste all of that code as a test version into the console)